# Google Cloud ML Engine: Access Model in Other GCS Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have editor access to a friend's GCS bucket which contains a machine learning model.  I want to create a new model version in my own project that uses his model.

When I go to `Create a New Version`, I have to specify the `gs:// Model URI` and it only lets me select my own buckets as locations for a model.

I'm able to download his model onto my local machine, so I feel like this should be possible.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify: are you manually typing in the name, or are you using "Browse"?

Comment: Also, can you be specific about any error messages you get, etc.?

Comment: @rhaertel80 I'm using Browse.  I just can't see my friend's buckets, which makes me think I'm not able to link to it.  Should I just use the `gs// URI` even so?

Comment: @rhaertel80 I tried manually typing in the model URI and hitting "Save".  Doesn't go through / show up as a new version :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually type the path to your friend's bucket or use the Shell and run this command:

`gcloud ml-engine versions create <VERSION_NAME> \
--model <MODEL_NAME> \
--origin <BUCKET> \
--runtime-version 1.9`

Remember to add *read privilege* to Cloud ML's service account in your friend's bucket or you will get an error like:

`description: Read permissions are required for Cloud ML service account <service account>
      to the model file gs://<BUCKET>/saved_model.pb.`

Here's a quickstart [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction) where you can check a little bit more info.

Comment: Just tried that and I get back: `FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: version.deployment_uri Error: Deployment directory gs://my_path/export/ is expected to contain exactly one of: [saved_model.pb, saved_model.pbtxt].` . I checked this location and it does contain `saved_model.pb` so I'm a bit lost...

Comment: You need to have the path to the folder containing the model, check the documentation I sent, it's explained there

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient that *you* have access to the data. You need to explicitly grant the Cloud ML Engine service permission to access that data. You can find instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/working-with-cloud-storage#setup-different-project